# Error turning windows features on in Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit

On 64bit Windows 7 system RTM (fully patched), I'm trying to "turn windows features on".

I select a few items (say "Games" or "Telnet Client"), and I keep getting the following error:

> An Error has occurred. Not all of the
>   features were successfully changed.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Silly me, I found the answer - I was trying this from a non-administrator user account.

Switching to an admin account worked.